# CSS dropdown not showing due to overflow property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making an Angular/Rails app now. I have a header configured on top of the screen and putting a dropdown functionality on an img.I essentialy wanna make dropdown for user information. Like one in Google. Due to `overflow: auto` in `page-header` CSS property, dropdown is not shown. However, I cannot take that property out because it will kill CSS on header if I take it out. How can I override it just for `dropdown` CSS?

Here are my codes:

```
<header class="page-header page-header--fixed">
        <a href="/" class="page-header-logo"><img src="/assets/logo-green.svg" alt="logo"></a>

        <div class="dropdown">
        <img src="/assets/user_icon.svg" alt="User" onclick="myFunction()">
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#home">Home</a>
                <a href="#about">About</a>
                <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
.page-header {
    overflow: auto;
        /*height:50px;*/
    padding: 8px 20px;
    background-color: #07b1d1;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.page-header--fixed {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    border-top: 0;
    background-color: white;
}

.dropdown {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    z-index: 200;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F5F8F9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    right: 0;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var x= document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
x.style.overflow= "auto";
```

Comment: I put it in window.onclick  function and did nothing.

Comment: can you provide a jsfindle

Comment: the problem it is "img onclick="myFunction()" " img cant do this

Comment: put inside a button the onclick="myFunction()"

Comment: you just need insert the js on the body after the dropdown or run the js auto start

Comment: drop down should be inside the header `<header class="page-header page-header--fixed">`. I need those CSS for my webapp. I know dropdown itself works fine. That wasn't my question tho.

Comment: just remove the overflow of header and change the position for absolute

Comment: HudsonPH's fiddle appears to solve your problem. here is a variation using document.querySelectorAll  to only loop over dropdowns that have the show class to being with:  https://jsfiddle.net/wzevgtrr/

Answer (score 0):

just add   `overflow:hidden` to your css rule for the  `.dropdown-content` class.

```
.dropdown-content {
        z-index: 200;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #F5F8F9;
        min-width: 160px;
        overflow: auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        right: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything. And why would I add another overflow?

Comment: oh, sorry, I missed that. do you want to toggle the overflow property of .dropdown-content during a click event? what are the conditions in which you want it to be hidden versus auto?

Comment: whenever I click the img, I want to show dropdown. But it is not shown due to overflow in page-header.